# When a class has some virtual methods, do all it's methods use a vtable?

Tags: c++, vtable

In this example below, Type has a virtual method so it has a vtable. However, Type::Bar() is not virtual. When calling Bar(), does the call also go through the vtable mechanism, or will it only apply to Foo()?

```
struct Base {
  virtual void Foo() {}
}

struct Type : Base {
  void Foo() override {}
  void Bar() {}
}

Base* b = new Type();
Type* t = static_cast<Type*>(b);
t->Bar(); // Does this use a vtable?
```

Comment: The word `vtable` appears exactly *zero* times in the ISO C++ standard, it is an implementation detail. Hence you should specify *which* implementation you're interested in.

Comment: @paxdiablo Do you know of any implementation that either does not use vtables or use vtables for non virtual functions or implements vtables very differently?

Comment: @curiousguy: no, I don't. But the whole point of a standard is to lock down certain things and, whatever the standard doesn't lock down, implementations are free to do whatever they want.

Comment: @paxdiablo Implementations are also free to add calls to `sleep(1)`...

Comment: Yes, they are. Inserting sleeps is less likely since (other than possibly slowing down code for debugging) there appears to be little upside. However, like the vtable issue, you should not rely on your code running at some arbitrary speed.

Comment: No compiler I know of inserts such things as totally absurd accesses to the vtable. You can expect the compiler not to do something so silly. The time it takes to run code depends on many things outside the control of the compiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> However, `Type::Bar()` is not `virtual`. When calling `Bar()`, does the call also go through the vtable mechanism, or will it only apply to `Foo()`?

The function to call for non-`virtual` functions is decided at compile time. Hence, there is no good reason for an implementation to choose the `vtable` to dispatch a call to a non-`virtual` function. However, the standard doesn't prohibit an implementation from using a `vtable` even for non-`virtual` functions.

@EJP said it better:

The standard doesn't require an implementation to use vtable for virtual functions. It's an implementation detail. No sane implementation using vtables would waste space in them by including non-virtual functions

Comment: It would be more accurate to say that the standard doesn't require an implementation to use  `vtable` for `virtual` functions. It's an implementation detail. No sane implementation using `vtables` would waste space in them by including non-`virtual` functions.

Answer (score 1):

The concept of a *vtable* is an implementation detail that's not further mentioned in the c++ standard.

But if there are non virtual functions provided at a class there's certainly no need to include them there, but fully bind the calls at compile time